# static custom dialog box Android

Tags: android, static, customdialog

I want to create a static customdialog box and want to access it in another class.

However , i am getting error if i pass current class in it.

here is my code:

```
public  static void showcustomdialogbox(String str,String type)
{
    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);//error line

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialogimageview);
dialog.show();

}
```

the error coming is `-cannot use in static context(error line)`
So,what should i pass in context??

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do this.  Dialogs only make sense in the context of an Activity (or in rare cases a service).  They require a Context to show, and they keep a reference to that Context.  So if you have a static reference to a Dialog, you have a static reference to its Context.  This will persist even after the Activity or Service exits.  So you've now leaked that Activity.  This means you also leaked all of the variables held by that activity, including View objects, their associated bitmaps, etc.  This could be 10s of megabytes, enough to cause you OutOfMemory problems later on.  The rule is you NEVER have a static Context variable.